# Telegram API: How to export contact from a group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to get contacts (user ids) from a particular group? Will telegram API support this functionality?

Comment: Telegram's ToS ordered you only reply to user's message, and don't be sender first of message

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to get all contacts of a group with the Telegram Bot API.

The closest you can get is to use [getChatAdministrators](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators) to receive a list of all administrators in the specified group.